# Which one is better approach for clear arrayList?

Tags: java

I need to clear the array list,Which one is better approach?Why?

**Approach 1 :**

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("ram");

if(list!=null)
{
  list.clear();
}
```

**Approach 2:**

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("ram");

if(list!=null && !list.isEmpty())
{
  list.clear();
}
```

In the approach 1, I don't check whether list is empty or not,directly i have been clear the list.

But in the approach 2, i have been clear the list if the list is not empty by checking

```
if(list!=null && !list.isEmpty())
```

Which one is better approach?Approach 1 or approach 2?

Comment: Just clear. Don't even check for `null` if you know it's not `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the implementation, for ArrayList for example (this is its `clear` method's code):

```
     public void clear() {
         modCount++;

         // Let gc do its work
         for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
             elementData[i] = null;

         size = 0;
     }
```

Means that the code doesn't spend more time if the list is already empty. In this sense I would just clear the code as you did with the first approach.

Answer (score 7):

Number one, try to use generics:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("ram");
```

Since it's initialized now, there is no need for null checks.

Now, if there is a specific contract you need to uphold to, you can check if the list is not empty, but as @Puce said, it's micro optimization.

```
list.clear();
```

Answer (score 2):

As for the source code of [`clear()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.clear%28%29) it does not check if the collection is empty or not.

```
public void clear() {
    modCount++;

    // Let gc do its work
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        elementData[i] = null;

    size = 0;
}
```

But this is a very little optimization, I guess you should take care of this only if you are having performance problems.

You can use both versions, and anyway if the list is not empty you wanted to clear it, and if the list is empty, then the clear() method will be very quick to execute, so... Don't bother

Comment: Actually: it's pretty much a no-op if the list is empty: it increases `modCount`, loops 0 times and then sets `size` to the same value it already is.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter. The overhead of `clear()` vs a check against `isEmpty()` is 1 line of code, a `modcount++;`

Answer (score 1):

It depends how `clear()` is implemented. This is a micro optimization at the most, so I recommend not to spend too much time thinking about this.

Comment: Yeah. `&& !list.isEmpty()` is quite silly. I bet `clear()` method also does that before flushing the list.

Answer (score 1):

Since `ArrayList` is array-based, you don't need to check whether is it empty or not. Therefore, I favourite the first approach because of its "micro" high performance

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the list again.

```
List list = new ArrayList();
 list.add("ram");

 if(list!=null && !list.isEmpty())
 {
   list = new ArrayList();
 }
```

Comment: @Puce who said about general rule. i only mentioned ,its best to do this to get a fresh list.

Comment: even if i said it as a general rule ? what is the problem in it ? :)

Comment: Well, it has it's own micro issues such as creating a new object, discarding the old one, but this shouldn't really matter. It's a design question: sometimes clear() fits better sometimes creating a new ArrayList. There is no clear winner, no "best way".

Comment: +1 agreed that there is no "best way". but i still feels its better than clear. :D